# Using edit control styles for rich edit

Tags: winapi

I've got a Rich Edit Control, created like this,

```
            box = CreateWindowEx(
                0, 
                MSFTEDIT_CLASS, 
                L"Type here", 
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | SS_OWNERDRAW,
                position.x,
                position.y,
                dimensions.x,
                dimensions.y,
                owner,
                0,
                hinst,
                0);
```

The documentation indicates that `ES_LEFT` will left-align the text, which is what I'm looking for. But when I add it to the list of styles, nothing happens. How can I set this edit control style?

Comment: `SS_OWNERDRAW` is a not a valid window style for RichEdit controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you would any other style in the fourth parameter of `CreateWindowEx()`:

```
WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | ES_LEFT
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine now that I'm not adding SS_OWNERDRAW. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define ES_CENTER   1
#define SS_OWNERDRAW 0xd
```

it's microsoft BUG:
unfortunatly `ES_CENTER` is included in `SS_OWNERDRAW`.